# KeyError: 'PKCS11_MODULE'

Tags: python, module, keyerror, pkcs#11, python-3.10

I am trying to work with the PKCS11 Python Module. I am following the procedure defined here: https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I am using python 3.10.6 on an Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine. I am running this python project in a virtual environment however I have gotten the same error without.

Here is the code I am trying to run from the site I pasted under RSA:

```
import pkcs11
# Note I added this import os
import os

lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PKCS11_MODULE'])
token = lib.get_token(token_label='DEMO')

data = b'INPUT DATA'

# Open a session on our token
with token.open(user_pin='1234') as session:
    # Generate an RSA keypair in this session
    pub, priv = session.generate_keypair(pkcs11.KeyType.RSA, 2048)

    # Encrypt as one block
    crypttext = pub.encrypt(data)
```

The error I receive is here:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'PKCS11_MODULE'
KeyError: b'PKCS11_MODULE'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/mack/Desktop/RSAvsCK/Broken Attempts/RSA_gen.py", line 4, in <module>
    lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PKCS11_MODULE'])
KeyError: 'PKCS11_MODULE'
```

I am unsure how to procede on this. The site this code is from specifies:

"Assuming your PKCS#11 library is set as PKCS11_MODULE and contains a token named DEMO:"

Which could be a source of the problem as I am unsure how to verify or edit this.

Comment: Your HSM/smartcard comes with a dynamic library called a pkcs11 module (or driver, provider, etc...). You need to provide full path to this library in an environment variable named `PKCS11_MODULE` (e.g. via command `export PKCS11_MODULE=/usr/safenet/lunaclient/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so`). This should get you past the initialization of library (assuming your device is installed correctly). To get further you will need to create a token named `DEMO` with user password set to `1234`. Please do read the documentation of your device/card for more information.

Comment: @vlp Thanks for the help! I am simply trying to use pkcs11 to do some text encryption for a school project, and don't have an HSM/smartcard.  I used the command ` export PKCS11_MODULE=/home/mack/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkcs11/_pkcs11.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so ` as well as a few other paths (within venv for example) and either get that its not a pkcs11 library or no such file found. I'm fairly sure I have the path correct as I took the dirname of the .so , but am not sure how to proceed. Obviously I'm very new so your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Then have a look at [softhsm](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2).